# How to replace lines that start with > with the 15 column of the same line by awk command?

Tags: linux, awk, gsub

I have file which looks like this:

```
 >gi|358482566|ref|NW_003766328.1| Gallus gallus breed Red Jungle fowl, inbred line UCD001 unplaced genomic scaffold, Gallus_gallus-4.0 ChrUn_7180000961607, whole genome shotgun sequence
 TCTGTCTCTTGTCACTGTATTGTAGTGTGAACCCCTTAAAGGGAAGACCTGCTCTCCTTTGAAAATGCTT
 GCTCATCTATATGCCTCATGCATACCCTCACTGGCAAAGGAGAGCTGAAGTAATTTTAGGACAGAGGAGT
 ACTAGATTGTA
 >gi|358482565|ref|NW_003766329.1| Gallus gallus breed Red Jungle fowl, inbred line UCD001 unplaced genomic scaffold, Gallus_gallus-4.0 ChrUn_7180000961609, whole genome shotgun sequence
 TTTGACCAATGCATTTCAGCATGTTTTTTGACACTAGGTATGCCATTTGGGATGACAATATCAGTTTCCA
 TTTCCATTAGAGGAAAATAAGGTT
```

I want to replace all the lines that start with `>`with its 15th column. what I don't know is how to replace the line with a column so I was trying to replace all the columns of that line by 15th column.

so what I expect to have as an output is:

```
     >ChrUn_7180000961607
     TCTGTCTCTTGTCACTGTATTGTAGTGTGAACCCCTTAAAGGGAAGACCTGCTCTCCTTTGAAAATGCTT
     GCTCATCTATATGCCTCATGCATACCCTCACTGGCAAAGGAGAGCTGAAGTAATTTTAGGACAGAGGAGT
     ACTAGATTGTA
     >ChrUn_7180000961609
     TTTGACCAATGCATTTCAGCATGTTTTTTGACACTAGGTATGCCATTTGGGATGACAATATCAGTTTCCA
     TTTCCATTAGAGGAAAATAAGGTT
```

these are my commands:

```
 awk '{if ($1 ~ />/) for (i=1; i<=19; i++) gsub ($i, $15)}'
 test.fa
```

when I use this I get some changes in the file but not what I want!! the column 15 is removed!!!

```
 awk '{if ($1 ~ />/) for (i=1; i<=19; i++) a= $15 gsub($i, a)}'
 gga_ref_Gallus_gallus-4.0_unplaced.fa
```

and when I use this one I get this error!

```
awk: (FILENAME=gga_ref_Gallus_gallus-4.0_unplaced.fa FNR=1) fatal: sub_common: buf: can't allocate 521711124992 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory)
```

so what I want is two replace a**ll the lines that start with** `>`with the **15th column** and I want to still **have `>`in the beginning**!

Comment: Do you care about the commas that are part of the 15th field? You don't show them in the sample output, even though they're part of the field.

Comment: Isn't this pipe-separated data?  If you're talking about fields, you need a different field separator.  Also, wouldn't it be a lot easier to use perl for this?

Comment: @tchrist If you look at the data, it appears to be whitespace-separated fields; that confused me at first, too. Seeing as it's trivial in awk, I can't imagine it would possible for it to be a lot easier in perl.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber It was the `for` loop that made me think it would be easier in perl than in awk, since perl has fancier regexes where that wouldn’t be required but I see that it isn’t actually needed after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
awk '$0 ~ /^>/ { print ">" $15; next } 1'
```

It leaves all lines that do not start with `>` unchanged. This is accomplished by using `next` to tell awk to skip to the next record for the case of lines starting with `>`. The `1` is there because it is always true, so the default action of printing the line is invoked for any line that does not start with `>`.

Comment: can you tell me what dose 1 do please??

Comment: @mahmood Edited into the answer. Let me know if it's not clear enough.

Comment: @mahmood instead of the `1`, you could have a rule that said `{print}` - more characters but clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed 's/^\(\s*\)>\(\S*\s*\)\{15\}.*/\1\2/;s/,\s*$//' file
```